# ¿Cuál es el origen de "macarrónico"?

Tags: etimología, italiano

[**Macarrónico**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NlfD87k) aparece definido en el DLE como:

> 1. adj. Dicho del latín: Usado de forma burlesca y defectuosa.
> 2. adj. Dicho de una lengua distinta del latín: Usada de forma notoriamente incorrecta.

pero sin ninguna indicación sobre su etimología.

Aparece ya en textos de principios del siglo XVII, como en el Quijote de Avellaneda (1614):

> "... avía travado plática, hablándolos en un latín **macarrónico** y lleno de ... "

Parece que debería tener alguna relación con [**macarrón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NlaNbG5):

> Del it. dialect. *maccarone*, y este del gr. bizant. *μακαρώνεια makarṓneia* 'felicidad para siempre', dicho en las comidas funerarias.
>
> 1. m. Pasta alimenticia de harina que tiene forma de canuto más o menos alargado. U. m. en pl.
>   2. m. Bollito con azúcar, almendra y otras especias.
>   3. m. Tubo delgado, generalmente de plástico flexible y resistente, que se emplea, entre otras cosas, para recubrir cables eléctricos o en tapicería.
>   4. m. Mar. Extremo de las cuadernas que sale fuera de las bordas del buque. U. m. en pl.

pero no alcanzo a verla, por lo que me pregunto sobre el origen de **macarrónico** y su *posible* relación con **macarrón**.

Answer (score 4):

Para añadir algunos detalles a la respuesta de @ukemi, en italiano existe el adjetivo "maccheronico" o "maccaronico", que hoy en día se usa con el mismo significado que el adjetivo español "macarrónico". El [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI09/GDLI_09_ocr_355.pdf)  indica que deriva del término "maccherone" entendido como "cibo grossolano", es decir, alimento vulgar, rústico. Este diccionario explica que este adjetivo (el diccionario indica que se usaba también la forma "maccheronesco") tiene origen
 en los ambientes humanísticos de las cortes de Mantua y Padua del siglo XV con el siguiente significado:

> Che appar­tiene  o  si  riferisce  a  un modo  di  esprimersi, e  soprattutto  di  verseggiare,  risalente  al  se­colo  XV,  in  un  latino  spropositato  o *grossus*, quale  in  realtà  si  poteva  ravvisare  negli  atti di  notai  o  udire  nel  parlare  di  ecclesiastici  in­colti  e  appunto  degno  di  quella  gente  rozza  ed ignorante,  amante  di  scorpacciate  di  ‘macche­roni’,  ossia  di  ‘gnocchi’;  i  versi  sono  sempre quantitativi e presentano un fondo lessicale ita­liano,  bresciano,  mantovano  e  latino,  così  come 
>   rigorosamente  latine,  a  parte  volute  e  sistema­tiche  variazioni,  sono  la  morfologia,  la  sintassi e  la  metrica;  l’uso  di  comporre  e  verseggiare in tale lingua sorse in ambienti umanistici veneti 
>   (Padova  e  Mantova)  per  mettere  in  burla  la goffaggine involontariamente volgareggiante degli ignoranti  che  si  avventuravano  a  esprimersi  in latino ed ebbe il migliore rappresentante in
>   Teofilo Folengo (1491-1544).

Mi traducción (que seguro se puede mejorar) sería:

> Que pertenece o se refiere a una manera de expresarse y, sobretodo, de componer versos, originaria del siglo XV, en un latín lleno de errores o *grossus*, el cual en realidad se podía reconocer en actas de notarios o escuchar en el modo de hablar de eclesiásticos incultos y que se consideraba precisamente típico de la gente rústica y ignorante amante de darse grandes atracones de  ‘*macche­roni*’,  es decir, de  ‘*gnocchi*’; los versos son siempre cuantitativos, presentan un fondo léxico ita­liano,  bresciano,  mantuano  y  latín, y la sintaxis y la métrica, a parte de algunas variaciones intencionales y sistemáticas, son también rigurosamente latinas; la práctica de escribir y componer versos en este tipo de lengua surgió en ambientes humanísticos vénetos (Padua  y  Mantua) con la intención de burlarse de la torpeza involuntariamente vulgarizante de los ignorantes que se aventuraban a expresarse en latín y tuvo su mejor representante en Teofilo Folengo (1491-1544).

Por cierto, los "gnocchi" de esa época, que también se llamaban "[maccheroni](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI09/GDLI_09_ocr_354.pdf)" (o bien "maccaroni", "macaroni" o "macheroni"), no eran los mismos que conocemos en la actualidad porque, obviamente, la patata todavía no se había introducido en Europa. La voz "[gnocco](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI06/GDLI_06_ocr_949.pdf)" del mismo diccionario explica que este vocablo, que también es de origen véneto, se utilizaba para denominar a unos pequeños panecillos de forma redonda a los que se añadía anís para que fueran más gustosos.

Este mismo diccionario explica que la palabra italiana "maccheronea", "macaronea" o "maccaronea" se utilizaba para denominar a las composiciones literarias escritas en esta lengua latina macarrónica. Y da el siguiente origen para este término:

> Dal  titolo  dell’opera *Maccheronea*
>     di  Tifi  Odasi (seconda  metà  del  sec.  XV),  precursore  di  T.  Folengo (1491-1544),  autore  di  un’opera  omonima,  da *maccherone*, nel  senso  di  ‘cibo  grossolano’.

Es decir, proviene de *Maccheronea*, título de una obra de Tifi Odasi (segunda mitad del  siglo XV),  precursor  de  Teofilo Folengo (1491-1544), autor de una obra homónima, que a su vez proviene de *maccherone*, en el sentido de alimento rústico.

Answer (score 3):

*Macarrónico* viene del neolatín *macaronicus*, que viene del neapolitano *maccarone* (que en esa época, significaba una *mezcla* cruda de harina, mantequilla y queso):

> The form was first written by Tisi [sic] degli Odassi in the late 15th century and popularized by Teofilo Folengo, a dissolute Benedictine monk who applied Latin rules of form and syntax to an Italian vocabulary in his burlesque epic of chivalry, Baldus (1517; *Le maccheronee,* 1927–28). **He described the macaronic as the literary equivalent of the Italian dish, which, in its 16th-century form, was a crude m̲i̲x̲t̲u̲r̲e̲ of flour, butter, and cheese.**
>
> - https://www.britannica.com/art/macaronic

Comment: Parece similar al uso de palabras como "ensalada" o "guiso" para referirse a cosas mezcladas o desordenadas.

Comment: @pablodf76: Más que a algo desordenado o mezclado como una "ensalada" el diccionario que he citado en mi respuesta lo asocia a una comida rústica o vulgar.

Comment: @pablodf76: Además, según lo que he encontrado en el diccionario que he citado en mi respuesta, parece ser que los "maccheroni" a los que se referían los inventores de las "maccheronee" (que eran vénetos) eran en realidad los antiguos "gnocchi", unos pequeños panecillos redondos (lo he incluido en mi respuesta).

Comment: Por cierto, es "[Tifi degli Odassi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michele_di_Bartolomeo_degli_Odasi)" (se encuentra también en la [*Enciclopedia Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tifi-odasi/)) y no "Tisi". Probablemente la Encyclopaedia Britannica ha confundido la "f" con la "[S larga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_larga)" que se solía usar en esa época. De hecho, "Tifi" era un pseudónimo que este autor escogió en honor de [Tifis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tifis), el timonel de los argonautas.